# Creating a PagerView inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make a PagerView inside a RecyclerView using `androidx` widgets, here is my code:

`ManageCategories.jt (Fragment)`

```
class ManageCategories : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    //TODO make json for categories
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_categories, container, false)
    val array = arrayOf("this", "is", "a", "test")
    val viewAdapter = CategoryRecyclerAdapter(array)
    val templateList = root.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.template_manage_category)
    val itemDecoration: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
    templateList.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
    templateList.adapter = viewAdapter

    return root

}
}
```

`fragment_manage_categories.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.templates.templates.ManageTemplates">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/template_manage_category"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The fragment gets inflates and sets a RecyclerAdapter**

`CategoryRecyclerAdapter.kt`

```
class CategoryRecyclerAdapter(private val myDataset: Array<String>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryViewHolder {
    val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_category, parent, false)
    return CategoryViewHolder(layout)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                Log.d("TEXT", "backup")
            }
        }
    }
    //TODO uncomment holder.textView.text = myDataset[position]
}

override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size

}
```

`CategoryViewHolder.kt`

```
class CategoryViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
init {
    val vp = v.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.category_pager)
    val pagerAdapter = CategoryPagerAdapter()
    vp.adapter = pagerAdapter
}
}
```

`list_category.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/category_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The RecyclerAdapter inflates each recycled view (4 times) with some dummy data ("this" "is" "a" "test") 
when the ViewHolder is called it initializes the PagerView and sets its adapter (I have tried to do this in a ViewHolder and the RecyclerAdapters onCreateViewHolder() method but it made no difference)**

`CategoryPagerAdapter.kt`

```
class CategoryPagerAdapter: PagerAdapter() {
override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
    return view === `object`
}

override fun getCount() = 2

override fun instantiateItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewGroup {
    val view: CategoryModel = CategoryModel.values().get(position)
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(collection.context)
    val layout = inflater.inflate(view.layoutResId, collection, false) as ViewGroup

    collection.addView(layout)
    return layout
}

override fun destroyItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int, view: Any) {
    collection.removeView(view as View?)
}
}
```

`CategoryModel.kt`

```
enum class CategoryModel(val layoutResId: Int) {
TEXT(R.layout.category_list_item),
BUTTONS(R.layout.button_pager);
}
```

`category_list_item.kt`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:padding="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`button_pager.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="world"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:padding="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The PagerAdapter then begins to inflate views with static text in place of RecyclerView Views with 2 PagerViews both of which are holding dummy text ("hello" "world"). This doesn't appear to work, I cant figure out why.

I have put the code through the debugger
the Recycler is being inflated 4 times
the Pager is being inflated 2 times with the correct layout files each time

yet I can't see any text, and when I try to findViewById for the TextViews the debugger returns false.

Whats going on? why can't I see the text?

**EDIT:**

To test I decided to remove the recycler so that only the pager was in use:

`ManageCategories.jt (Fragment)`

```
class ManageCategories : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    //TODO make json for categories
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_category, container, false)
    val pagerAdapter = CategoryPagerAdapter()
    val pager: ViewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.category_pager)
    pager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    return root

}
}
```

This worked as expected and the Pager layout worked fine. In a seperate test I removed the Pager layout and that also worked fine. I just can't get the two to work together.

My current working theory is that I am trying to inflate the view within `CategoryViewHolder` through `CategoryPagerAdapter` something I found out about `RecyclerView` was that it doesn't like inflating views within its `ViewHolder`. I just don't know where to put it.

**EDIT2:**

I have moved the code that initializes `CategoryPagerAdapter` into `onCreateViewHolder` and/or `onBindViewHolder` method of `CategoryRecyclerAdapter`.

After further investigation I have found that `instantiateItem()` is returning a proper `ViewGroup` of inflated views inside`CategoryPagerAdapter`. However, for whatever reason when I try to inspect the object/views outside of the class(CategoryRecyclerAdapter) pagerAdapter they appear to be emtpy. I am confident that when I can figure out why it is getting null that the functionality will be working as expected, but I can't figure out why. Please help.

**EDIT3:**

I figured that since the pager was inflating the views, according to the values in the debugger. But then when inspecting the pager inside the recycler that views were no longer present, naturally I thought they were using different inflaters.

I compared the two inflaters used in the Logs and they are both the same object, so its not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the functionality by using a ViewPager2 since ViewPager is no longer actively being worked on;

```
class CategoryPagerAdapter(private val model: Array<CategoryModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryPagerViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryPagerViewHolder {
    val view = model[viewType].layoutResId
    val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(view, parent, false)
    return CategoryPagerViewHolder(layout)
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = position

override fun getItemCount() = model.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                Log.d("TEXT", "backup")
            }
        }
    }
}
}

class CategoryPagerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

Here is a barely working version of the code. Text isn't properly being updated yet.